# how to remove the spaces in the site

Tags: html, css, web, web-deployment

I am having a small problem 
how can I remove the space between my header and the navigation bar  and my header and the top of the screen !
here it is the image :

http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/fa087570.png

I am also having another problem  and that is when I use the "float: left" in the navbar it disappears !!! why !?

here is the code I am running

http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/pd387794.png

Waitting for your answer !

Comment: Can you post the HTML/CSS and create a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the pictures aren't working !?

Comment: I think the `padding` element on `.header h1` is creating the space, no?

Remove that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Try `h1 {margin:0;}`.

Comment: Please paste your code in a code snippet or JsFiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ve069kap/

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome debugger to inspect the `h1` tag, and you'll see it's because of the browser default CSS, that you're not removing/overring the margin being applied to the `h1`

Comment: h1 {margin:0;} 
it worked

Comment: and what about the "float"
""I am also having another problem and that is when I use the "float: left" in the navbar it disappears !!! why !?""

Comment: Your navbar then has no height reference as your items are floating. You'll either have to add an element and apply an clearing item or use inline-block.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ve069kap/2/

Add padding to the header, not the H1.

```
.header {
    background-color: #4a4849;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #0097ff;
    border-left: 2px solid #0097ff;
    }


.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0;
    margin:0px;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #0097ff;
    border-left: 2px solid #0097ff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you
I already figure it out !

Answer (score 1):

Change the margin on `h1`:

```
.header h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the margin on the h1; H1 tags have a standard margin/padding. You also had a double border so i removed the border-right and border-left on the h1.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}

/* start header */
.header {
    background-color: #4a4849;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #0097ff;
    border-left: 2px solid #0097ff;
    }


.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin:0px;
    color: #fff;
}

.header h1 span {
    color: #0097ff;
    }
/* end header */
/* start navbar */

.navbar {
    background-color: #4a4849;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #0097ff; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0097ff;
}

.navbar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: inline;
}

/* end navbar */

img {
    height: 590px;
    width: 100%;
}
```